# How to formalize "if and only" in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to formalize and proof the validity of "If I train or if I don't train if and only my friend competes, I'll go to the meeting"

- p = I train
- q = my friend competes
- r = go to the meeting

My guess is **(p ∨ (¬ p ↔ q)) → r**, but I'm not sure about what "if and only" means in this case.

Comment: i have no idea how to parse that phrase.  Don't even know what "I'll go to the evening" means.  I expect there is a language issue here.

Comment: What does it mean "if and only"? We have "if and only if".

Comment: That is exactly my question. This is directly copied from an exercise. Maybe there is a typo in the question itself? And if we suppose that they made a typo and the correct phrase is: "If I train or if I don't train if and only if my friend competes, I'll go to the meeting", is my solution correct?

Comment: My best guess to fix the broken question is to turn "if and" into "and if". It then becomes meaningful but ambiguous English, probably intended to to mean $(p \lor (\lnot p \land q)) \to r$ (where $q$ means "only my friend competes"), suggesting that you don't think you need to train to beat your friend. However, your interpretation and mine are not valid without further assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your help!